# i have a jquery code to export table into csv but i want a prompt through which i can save my file name

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('table').each(function() {
    var $table = $(this);

    var $button = $("<button type='button'>");
    $button.text("Export to csv");
    $button.insertAfter($table);

    $button.click(function() {

      function downloadFile(fileName, urlData) {

    var aLink = document.createElement('a');
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent("click");
    aLink.download = fileName;
    aLink.href = urlData;
    aLink.dispatchEvent(evt);
}


var data = $table.table2CSV({delivery:'suncity'});
downloadFile('suncity.csv', 'data:text/csv;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(data));
    });
  });
})
```

I'm trying to use something like this:

```
$("button").click(function(event) {
    // var outputFile = 'export'
    var outputFile = window.prompt("What do you want to name your output file (Note:  This won't have any effect on Safari)") || 'export';
    outputFile = outputFile.replace('.csv', '') + '.csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var filename = prompt("Save file as","suncity.csv");
if(filename){
   downloadFile(filename, 'data:text/csv;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(data));
}else{
   downloadFile("suncity.csv", 'data:text/csv;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(data));
}
```